# Google Contacts: trash?

Tags: google-contacts, google-workspace-for-business

I deleted the wrong contact on Google Contacts by mistake... I noticed there was briefly an `undo` option, but I didn't realise I needed it until later.

Is there a trash folder that I can retrieve it from? Or is the ability to restore a contact only temporary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same happened with me a month ago:-(

There is no option to retrieve the contact from a trash. Just like in Gmail.

You can however restore your contracts to a previous state by the undo option. But be careful it will restore you to that earlier point. It means any changes you made after that will be gone.

And what do you mean by ability to restore the contact? Clarify it a bit more. Will be happy to help :-)

Because all the changes made by the undo option are in your address book.